# The '<Image/>' Component in React Native can't load the picture with DNG extension in the iOS Platform

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image

I encountered some troubles when I used Image component like this

```
<Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{uri:'http://192.168.0.1/photos/photo.dng'}}/>
```

There are no any troubles DEBUG model. But if I change it to RELEASE model. It can't load pictures with DNG but JPG still be fine. I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.dng` is **not** currently supported by [Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#source)

> The currently supported formats are png, jpg, jpeg, bmp, gif, webp (Android only), psd (iOS only).

#### Why it worked when debugging

It may have worked while debugging if you had **remote debugging** enabled. When remote debugging with Chrome Dev Tools, Chrome will execute the javascript. Unfortunately, Chrome supports slightly different things than React Native.

Comment: Thank you for your help! First thing I want to say is that The debug model is set in Xcode not Chrome Dev Tool.And I can show photo with dng extension by using native code.Finally do you have any way to solve the problem? THX.

Comment: If there is native module that supports `.dng`, then you can write a native module for it. Here is the guide for [iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) and [Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)